# MVC View Details and Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I have a view which displays data from the database like a blog post and at the bottom I would like the ability for a user to comment, how would one achieve this?

Comment: in other news, questions with specifics received detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a form at the bottom of the view that will post to an action method. That action method will then process the form and save a comment against the blog post.

Comment: I get the following error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Blog.Web.Models.Post' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Blog.Web.Controllers.PostFormViewModel'.

Any ideas, just starting out in MVC :)

Comment: Going to take a wild stab as I have no details and say you've defined your view as View<PostFormViewModel> and then called View(post) in your action. It should instead pass a PostFormViewModel object instead of just the Post.

Comment: You are correct, I will have a play and see what I can come up with and let you know.